# Find the Oldest person from an array of persons which contains their name and yearOfBirth Java

Tags: java

I need to implement a method which should take an array of persons, basically public String oldest (Person [] persons), and return the oldest one. The persons which will be inputed are the following:

```
new Person("Augusta Ada King, grevinna av Lovelace", 1815),
new Person("Muhammad ibn Musa al-Khwarizmi", 780),
new Person("Alan Turing", 1912),
new Person("Grace Hopper", 1906)
```

Below you can find my class Called Person. I've tried all different solutions with basic for-loop but I feel really lost and would appreciate any input or recommendation how I should write the method to find the oldest person.

class Person {

```
String name;
int yearOfBirth;

public Person(String name, int yearOfBirth) {
this.name = name;
this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
}

public int getAge() {
return getAge(java.time.LocalDate.now().getYear());
}

public int getAge(int year) {
return year - yearOfBirth;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return String.format("%s %d", name, yearOfBirth);
}

public String oldest(Person [] persons){
 
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe add one of your solutions of how to find the oldest? It's always recommended here to base off the answers on something that you provide and so maybe highlight the actual issues in your thought process.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Person oldest = Arrays.stream(persons).max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)).get();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked and I learned something new about stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your `persons` array and check which `yearOfBirth` is greater. You can implement your method like below:

```
public String oldest(Person[] persons) {
        Person oldestPerson = persons[0];
        for (Person person : persons) {
            if (person.getYearOfBirth() < oldestPerson.getYearOfBirth()) {
                oldestPerson = person;
            }
        }
        return oldestPerson.getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This method should be static since it has nothing to do with an instance, and otherwise you have to call the method from an instance, which you probably don't want to do
2. Want should happen if you have more then one (oldest) person with the same age?
3. Why should the return be only the name and not a Person?

   ```
    public static String oldest(Person[] persons) {
        if (persons == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("persons == null");
        }
        if (persons.length == 0) {
            return null; //or throw same Exception depending on your handling
        }

        Person oldestPerson = persons[0];
        for (Person person : persons) {
            if (person.yearOfBirth < oldestPerson.yearOfBirth) {
                oldestPerson = person;
            }
        }
        return oldestPerson.name;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since there could be the possibility of more than one oldest person I would do it as follows:

Here is some data with two oldest people (sort of)

```
Person[] people = {
        new Person("Augusta Ada King, grevinna av Lovelace",
                1815),
        new Person("Muhammad ibn Musa al-Khwarizmi", 780),
        new Person("Another oldest person", 780),
        new Person("Alan Turing", 1912),
        new Person("Grace Hopper", 1906) };

String s = Person.oldest(people);
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
Muhammad ibn Musa al-Khwarizmi
Another oldest person
```

- first I would make the method static since it doesn't rely on instance fields but an array of instances.
- I would use a `map` to facilitate holding the the names of the people using their age as the key.  Use the `Map.merge` method to populate the map and handle duplicate ages
- Now iterate thru the names and as you do so:

  - find the oldest age.
  - store the name as the value for that age.
  - if another is found of the same age, concatenate the name with a newline(\n) and update the current map value.
- when finished, return the value for the computed oldest individual(s).

```
public static String oldest(Person[] persons) {
     int oldest = 0;
     Map<Integer, String> ages = new HashMap<>();
     for (Person p : persons) {
         int age = p.getAge();
         oldest = Math.max(oldest, age);
         ages.merge(age, p.name, (last, current)- > last + "\n" + current);
     }
     return ages.get(oldest);
}
```

In case you would rather return a List of names your method can look like this. The main differences are:

- return a `List<String>` which contains the names
- using a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` to contain the people based on age.
- `computeIfAbsent` to initialize the maps value for that age one time and then add the name to the list.

```
public static List<String> oldest(Person[] persons) {
     int oldest = 0;
     Map<Integer, List<String>> ages = new HashMap<>();
     for (Person p : persons) {
         int age = p.getAge();
         oldest = Math.max(oldest, age);
         ages.computeIfAbsent(age, v->new ArrayList<>()).add(p.name);
     }
     return ages.get(oldest);
}
```

It would then be called like so

```
List<String> list = Person.oldest(people);
list.foreach(System.out::println);  // to print - same as before.
```

My final recommendation is that you use Lists over Arrays as they have advantages, the main on (imho) being that they grow dynamically as you add more items.